# How do I create associations in rails4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

How do I generate models with these associations:

```
Owner 
has_many dogs

Dog
belongs_to :owner, has_many :puppies

Puppy
belongs_to :dog
```

I tried:

```
$ rails generate model Owner name:string
$ rails generate model Dog name:string owner_id:references
$ rails generate model Puppy name:string dog_id:references
```

and then I did this:

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dogs
end

class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
  has_many :puppies
end

class Puppy < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dog
end
```

But when I run:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

I get this error:

```
==  CreateOwners: migrating ==================================================
-- create_table(:owners)
   -> 0.0063s
==  CreateOwners: migrated (0.0064s) =========================================

==  CreateDogs: migrating ==============================================
-- create_table(:dogs)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)/Users/7stud/rails_projects/test1/db/migrate/20141011043159_create_dogs.rb:4:in `block in change'
```

...and here is 20141011043159_create_dogs.rb

```
class CreateDogs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :dogs do |t|
      t.name :string
      t.references :owner_id, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Full error message:

```
~/rails_projects/test1$ rails generate model Owner name:string
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20141011051648_create_owners.rb
      create    app/models/owner.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/models/owner_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/owners.yml

~/rails_projects/test1$ rails generate model Dog name:string owner:references
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20141011051712_create_dogs.rb
      create    app/models/dog.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/models/dog_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/dogs.yml

~/rails_projects/test1$ rails generate model Puppy name:string dog:references
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20141011051736_create_puppies.rb
      create    app/models/puppy.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/models/puppy_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/puppies.yml
```

Then I edited the models to look like this:

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dogs
end

class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
  has_many :puppies
end

class Puppy < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dog
end


~/rails_projects/test1$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
==  CreateOwners: migrating ===================================================
-- create_table(:owners)
   -> 0.0063s
==  CreateOwners: migrated (0.0065s) ==========================================

==  CreateDogs: migrating =====================================================
-- create_table(:dogs)
   -> 0.0017s
==  CreateDogs: migrated (0.0018s) ============================================

==  CreatePuppies: migrating ==================================================
-- create_table(:puppies)
   -> 0.0017s
==  CreatePuppies: migrated (0.0019s) =========================================
```

Yeehaw!  It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the _id from the declarations. Rails will generate it properly instead.
If you would to keep it that way, declare it as an integer.

Comment: I deleted the models and migrations, recreated the models with commands like `$ rails generate model Dog name:string owner:references` and I get the exact same error.

Comment: Worked like a charm here. Try the answer posted by anusha, which is the only difference between your migration and mine.

Comment: I even tried changing the names of the models, thinking there might be something I didn't delete properly, and I get the exact same error.  I'm giving up for the night.

Comment: By the way, eliminating _id from the generate commands only changed what rails put in the Models: `belongs_to :owner_id` v. `belongs_to :owner`, and I had edited that anyway to `belongs_to :owner`.

Comment: I tried running my generate commands again with the `_id`, e.g. `owner_id:references`, and when I edited the model files to look like what I posted, the migration worked.  So your suggestion was not the problem either.  I have no idea why nothing worked for me before and now it is working.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class CreateDogs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :dogs do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :owner_id

      t.timestamps
   add_index :dogs, :owner_id
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That migration produces the exact same error.  Line 4 is `t.string :name`

Comment: I had deleted everything, and when I tried to create the error again, the migration worked.  I posted what I did at the end of my post.  I have no idea why it worked this time.  I tried doing it with several different model names, and each time I got that same error.  Each time I deleted the migrations and models before trying again.  I don't know what was different that last time.

Comment: @7stud happy to hear that it worked if my answer helpful to u please accept it

Comment: Well, I didn't have to edit my migration files as you suggested--the migration files look like the one I originally posted.